# Como exibir em um listview dados via web api?

Tags: web-service, listview, asp.net-web-api, xamarin-forms

estou tendo dificuldades para realizar essa tarefa, preciso buscar dados que estão armazenados via `mysql` em um site e exibi-los em meu app que está sendo desenvolvido em `Xamarin Forms`, para isso preciso fazer um `webservice`. Eu tenho o seguinte contexto:
***No meu arquivo XAML***

```
<Label Text="Cliente" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
```

***Criei uma classe chamada ClienteRequest***

```
public  class ClienteRequest
    {
        public string cpfcnpj { get; set; }
        public string nomefantasia { get; set; }
    }
```

***e no meu codeBehind está assim provisoriamente***

```
 List<String> itens2 = new List<String>()
            {
                "dados do banco"
            };
        coluna2.ItemsSource = itens2;
```

Aqui seria o endereço de onde os dados serão consumidos:

> http://ativoproject.ebasesistemas.com.br

E aqui seria a url da determinada função:

> data/_obterclientescolaborador.php

Como ficaria para eu passar essas urls e recuperar esses dados exibindo os na listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
Apenas uma dica, seria muito melhor usar o padrão MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel).

Criei um uma View(xaml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SampleListBinding.Views.PersonsView">
 <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
        <!--Custom View Cells-->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

No codeBehind apenas apontei para a viewModel

```
public PersonsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new PersonsViewModel();
    }
```

e assim ficou minha ViewModel

```
public class PersonsViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return persons; }
        set
        {
            persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public PersonsViewModel()
    {
        GetPerson();
    }

    public void GetPerson()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        for(byte i =0; i< 20; i++)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.FirstName = $"Person FirstName {i}";
            p.FirstName = $"LastName {i}";
            Persons.Add(p);
        }
    }

}
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

[coloquei o código no github](https://github.com/sk9g3/SampleListBinding)

Comment: exatamente, eu fiz isso e ficou tudo ok